# Is there a function in pandas to group data with and without considering a condition at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkTwG.png)

I want to find number of home_matches and number of home_wins for each team in every season.
So my code is this:

```
> home_matches=viewmatches.groupby(["season","home_team"])["home_team"].count().reset_index(name="home_matches")
> home_wins=viewmatches[viewmatches.home_team_goal>viewmatches.away_team_goal].groupby(["season","home_team"])["home_team"].count().reset_index(name="home_wins")
> merged=home_wins.merge(home_matches, on=["season","home_team"]) 
> merged
```

and the result is this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6RBI.png)

But is there another way to get the same result without writing two group by functions and then merging two tables? For example in MySQL for the same result there is an easy query:

```
select season, home_team, count(home_team) as home_matches,
count(if(home_team_goal>away_team_goal,home_team,null)) as home_wins
from matches_view mv 
group by season, home_team
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use your own SQL code with Pandas and for more details you could check this link:
[sql-to-pandas-dataframe](https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/)
This is my preferred way of working with dataframes

so, in your case it would be:

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query ('''
                           SELECT
                           season, home_team, count(home_team) AS home_matches,
                           FROM matches_view mv group by season, home_team
                           ''', COUNT(if(home_team_goal>away_team_goal,home_team,null)) AS home_wins)
merged = pd.DataFrame(sql_query, columns = ['season','home_team'])
```